Pipeline unable to pull a ACR Image
When running a DevOps Pipeline, I can build and push the Docker image, the build fails when pulling image inside a Azure VM. Due to this error message:

##[error]Error response from daemon: Head "https://<ACR_NAME>.azurecr.io/v2/<IMAGE_NAME>/manifests/latest": unauthorized: {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information."}]}

I am unsure how to successfully SSH into a Linux VM and pull the image. Any guidance would be appreciated.
Here are the steps I have tried:

Installed the Azure CLI on the VM and used the AzureCLI@2 task to establish a session for pulling the image.
Created Service Connections for SSH and Docker Registry, as well as a Service Principal for authentication.
Tried without using the Azure CLI as well.

Here is my pipeline file:
variables:
  ACR_NAME: '<ACR_NAME>'
  IMAGE_NAME: '<IMAGE_NAME>'
  ACR_USER: '<ACR_USER>'
  VM_USER: '<VM_USER>'
  VM_HOST: '<VM_HOST>'
  SSH_CONN_NAME: '<SSH_CONN_NAME>'
  ACR_CONN_NAME: '<ACR_CONN_NAME>'
  RESOURCE_MANAGER_CONN: '<RESOURCE_MANAGER_CONN>'
  AIRFLOW_UID: '50000'

stages:
- stage: BuildAndDeploy
  displayName: 'Build and Deploy Stage'
  jobs:
  - job: BuildAndPush
    displayName: 'Build and Push Docker Image'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: DockerInstaller@0
      inputs:
        dockerVersion: '27.0.2'

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: 'Build the Docker Img'
      inputs:
        command: 'build'
        repository: '$(ACR_NAME).azurecr.io/$(IMAGE_NAME)'
        dockerfile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
        tags: 'latest'

    - task: DockerCompose@0
      displayName: 'Push the Docker Img'
      inputs:
        action: 'Push services'
        azureSubscriptionEndpoint: '$(RESOURCE_MANAGER_CONN)'
        azureContainerRegistry: '$(ACR_NAME)'
        dockerComposeFile: 'docker-compose.prod.yaml'
        projectName: '$(Build.Repository.Name)'
        additionalImageTags: |
          $(Build.BuildId)
          prod
        qualifyImageNames: true

  - job: Deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy to Azure VM'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: 'Azure CLI Login'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(RESOURCE_MANAGER_CONN)'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          az acr login --name $(ACR_NAME)

    - task: SSH@0
      displayName: 'Deploy using docker-compose on Azure VM'
      inputs:
        sshEndpoint: $(SSH_CONN_NAME)
        runOptions: 'inline'
        inline: |
          az acr login --name $(ACR_NAME)
          docker stop $(IMAGE_NAME) || true
          docker rm $(IMAGE_NAME) || true
          docker pull $(ACR_NAME).azurecr.io/$(IMAGE_NAME):latest
          cd $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
          docker-compose -f docker-compose.p.yaml up -d


I managed to resolve this by:

Going to the Azure VM > Identity > System Assigned > set to True and hit save
Azure role positions button > Added ArcPull and ArcPush roles
Back into the Project Settings > Service Connections > modified the Docker Registry to use the Managed Service Identity
In the azure-pipelines.yml in the job added to the existing inline script:

        runOptions: 'inline'
        inline: |
          # Step 1: Login into Azure
          az login --identity
          
          # Step 2: Authenticate ACR
          az acr login --name $(THE NAME OF YOUR ACR REGISTRY)

